# RxJS skipWhile vs filter

Tags: javascript, rxjs

What is the difference between skipWhile and filter operators?

```
const source = interval(1000);
const example = source.pipe(skipWhile(val => val < 5));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));


const source = interval(1000);
const example = source.pipe(filter(val => val > 5));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The difference is that upon its expression evaluating to `false`, skipWhile changes over to **mirroring** its source observable - so it will cease to filter out any further values.

For example:

```
Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .pipe(filter(val => val % 2 == 0)) // filters out odd numbers
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // emits 2,4

Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5])
  .pipe(skipWhile(val => val % 2 == 1)) // filters odd numbers until an even number comes along
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // emits 2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't fully understand it. Can you please make it more clear? maybe with another example? thanks.

Comment: @undefined `skipWhile` will only start emitting _all_ next values when the condition for the first time evaluates to `false`. `filter` will always filter every emitted value which does not conform to the given filter condition.

Comment: So skipWhile is a one-time filter.

Comment: skipWhile is a waste of time that makes developers angry - filter is what you want :D

Comment: @Seth But it can be very useful to wait for a Observable be the first time `connected`, like for a connection to a websocket

Comment: The operator should be definitely called skipUntil as this much better describes what it does

Answer (score 15):

```
Observable.from(["Citizen 1","Citizen 2","President","Citizen 3","Citizen 4"])
  .pipe(filter(val => val == "President")) // Only let the president into the bunker.
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // emits President

Observable.from(["Citizen 1","Citizen 2","President", "Citizen 3","Citizen 4"])
  .pipe(skipWhile(val => val != "President")) // Let the citizens enter the bunker, but only after the president enters.
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // emits President, Citizen 3, Citizen 4
```

Answer (score 5):

`skipWhile` operator will ignore the emissions until the specified condition becomes false, but after that, it will continue to take values from the source observable as is.

```
const randomNumbersLessThanEqualToTen = interval(1000).pipe(map((num) => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*num);
    console.log('Random Number Generated', randomNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}), skipWhile(num => num < 10));

randomNumbersLessThanEqualToTen.subscribe((number) => {
    console.log('Number not skipped', number);
});
```

o/p

```
Random Number Generated 6
Random Number Generated 0
Random Number Generated 5
Random Number Generated 0
Random Number Generated 5
Random Number Generated 11
Number not skipped 11
Random Number Generated 6
```

As soon as 11 (i.e. num < 10 === false) got generated and emitted all the generated numbers were taken and printed.

Here is an example of `filter`:

```
const randomNumbers = interval(1000).pipe(map((num) => {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    console.log('Random Number Generated', randomNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}), filter(num => num > 10));
randomNumbers.subscribe((number) => {
    console.log('Number is greater than 10 -->', number);
});
```

o/p

```
Random Number Generated 7
Random Number Generated 11
Number is greater than 10 --> 11
Random Number Generated 13
Number is greater than 10 --> 13
Random Number Generated 13
Number is greater than 10 --> 13
Random Number Generated 3
Random Number Generated 2
```

So above output simply showcased that filter simply filters the emissions on the basis of the condition specified and it filters throughout the lifetime of observable.